# how to retrieve items from pep pubsub xmpp protocol

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, strophe

How can I retrieve items using PEP pubsub XMPP protocol? I don't know how to retrieve history of PEP events. I tried with this stanza, but I am getting an "item not found" error.

```
<iq type='get'
    from='admin@domain.ddns.net'
    to='pubsub.domain.ddns.net'
    id='items1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <items node='http://jabber.org/protocol/tune'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error: item not found

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the request to `pubsub.domain.ddns.net`, i.e. a Pubsub service, but when using PEP, you need to send the requests to the bare JID of the contact, e.g. `user@domain.ddns.net`.  See [XEP-0163](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html) for more details.